# The file "/tmp/phpHh98PX" does not exist

Tags: php, symfony, file-upload, api-platform.com

I know this question has been asked many times but there is no answer that solved my problem.

**I DON'T WANT TO USE VichUploader**

What I want to do is very simple: save an entity with a file upload.

1. I receive my data correctly
2. The upload is done in the specified path
3. If I comment the upload script the entity is saved well

I can't get all the script to work, it stops on flush

**CODE**

*ClientDocument.php*

```
@ApiResource(
 ....
 *     collectionOperations={
 *         "get",
 *         "post" = {
 *             "controller" = DocumentController::class,
 *             "deserialize" = false
 *     }})
class ClientDocument extends PersonDocument {

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Client", inversedBy="clientDocuments")
     */
    private ?Client $client;

    // Getter and Setter
}
```

*SalarieDocument.php*

```
@ApiResource(
 ....
 *     collectionOperations={
 *         "get",
 *         "post" = {
 *             "controller" = DocumentController::class,
 *             "deserialize" = false
 *     }})
class SalarieDocument extends PersonDocument {

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Salarie", inversedBy="salarieDocuments")
     */
    private ?Salarie $salarie;

    // Getter and Setter
}
```

*PersonDocument.php*

```
/**
...
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")
...
class PersonDocument {

private ?string $reference;

* @Assert\File(
     *     maxSize="200ki",
     *     mimeTypes={"application/pdf", "image/jpeg", "image/jpg"}
     * )
     */
    private ?string $docFile;

// Getters and Setters
}
```

*DocumentController.php*

```
public function __invoke() {

    return $this->documentService->createPersonDocument($data, $files);
}
```

*DocumentService.php*

```
public function createPersonDocument(array $data, array $files) {
        $client = ....
        $personDocument = $this->createEditPersonDocument(new ClientDocument(), $data);
        $personDocument = $this->upload($person, $personDocument, $files[0]);
        $client->addClientDocuments($personDocument);
        $this->manager->persist($client);
        $this->manager->flush();

        return $personDocument;
    }
```

**Stack**

- PHP 7.4
- Symfony 5.3
- Api Platform 2.6

I didn't customize anything in php.ini (it's default), no advanced infrastructure (no docker or anything).

If I *dump* my objects before the *$this->manager->flush();* everything is good

Do you have any idea what is causing this error please ?

Comment: I'm guessing - Missing cascade persist on $clientDocument for the document ? 
What exactly is the error You are getting ? Also I would suggest splitting API platform from entity and doctrine configuration

Comment: Thank you @TomaszBuczeń for your reply 
I don't think that I m missing cascade persist because I m able to save my entity if I comment the upload script 
The error that I have is the title of issue : **The file "/tmp/phpHh98PX" does not exist** .
what do you mean by  splitting ? using yaml ?

Comment: any help :( is still there